# Adding a patch config file ONLY to my production server

Tags: unicorn, patch-configuration

I have another question where I needed to add another target database to my sync in unicorn. However I only need the patch to take affect in my production environment since my local errors out on the unicorn sync since I don't need the target database on local. So my DBs are web and web_uk but they are only on production environments. Is there any way I can get around the error on local environments?

Answer (score 12):

You can add role on your configuration into your patch config.

For example I created a patch config for setting up site definition for prod environment.

```
<site name="website1"
 env:require="PROD"
 role:require="ContentDelivery"
 patch:before="site[@name='website']"
 hostName="test.com"
 targetHostName="test.com"
 virtualFolder="/"
 physicalFolder="/"
 rootPath="/sitecore/content"
 startItem="/home"
 domain="extranet"
 allowDebug="false"
 cacheHtml="false"
 htmlCacheSize="10MB"
 disableClientData="false"
 contentLanguage="en"
 content="master"
 language="en"
 />
```

I think this example may help to understand adding patch configuration according to environment.

In web.config we need to add these settings as well

```
<!-- SUPPORTED ENVIRONMENTS
Specify the environment that you want this server to perform. A server can perform single environment. The supported environments are:

LOCAL
DEV
TEST
STAGE
PROD

Default value: Local
-->
<add key="env:define" value="PROD" />
```